# jquery ajax causing memory leak in IE9

Tags: html, json, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I update a page's values every 500 milliseconds and noticed that there is a memory leak in IE9 caused by jquery's `$.ajax` method.

Here's an example:

```
var refreshId = setInterval(refresh, 500);

function refresh() {

    $.ajax('/url/object?get=theObjectNeeded');
}
```

In the example I'm not doing anything with the values but normally it's a `JSON` request and I populate values based on that. Either way there is a memory leak.

I tried this same code with Firefox 4 and IE8 but the leak doesn't occur.

Has anyone else ran into this and does anyone know of a solution/hack? One thing that I could do is refresh the page every few hours to release memory but I don't want to have to do that.

Comment: @Darcy Can you test the following in ie9. The memory consumption does go up but garbage collection does kick in and clean up and regular intervals. http://jsfiddle.net/YCM4g/1/

Comment: Also be handy if you could post some proof of the leaks - how much is it leaking - over what sort of time periods etc

Comment: @redsquare - The garbage collection never gets called. I've had the memory increase to over 1.2GB on a machine with only 4GB's, and it never cleans up. In fact IE locks up when it reached that point. Also if I refresh the page every 500 milliseconds it only takes an hour or so to reach 1GB

Comment: @Darcy - what about the above test app? Did the same thing happen?

Comment: @redsquare. No the leak doesn't appear to occur. But the object being gotten is much smaller too, so maybe that has something to do with it. I'd also like to point out that on one of my test machines there was no leak at all in IE9 even though the versions are the exact same! (The OS is the same as well)

Comment: @Darcy - oddballed then! Reinstall ie9;) Be good if you can get a fiddle together that does leak.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the ajax requests are not being performed as quickly as they are stacked up. To prevent this, you could make sure that only one refresh request is happening at a time.

```
   function refresh() {
     $.ajax({
        url: '/url/object?get=theObjectNeeded', 
        success: function(){
          setTimeout(refresh, 500);
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: the response comes back in 100ms. Also, it doesn't matter if the timeout is 5 seconds or higher (it just takes longer to blow up)

Comment: @Darcy I see. But out of curiosity, does my solution work, or is there some reason you can't implement it?